# MySQL C++ Connector: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'

Tags: c++, mysql, makefile, mysql-connector

I've been trying to get the MySQL connector working I've installed both the connector and the mysql client library but I am still getting this error:

```
obj/Database.obj: In function `Database::connect()':
/home/xeross/alpine/src/server/Database.cpp:13: undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [alpine-server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Using Ubuntu 10.04
And my makefile is as follows:

```
INCLUDES = -I./src -I./src/shared
OUTDIR = bin
INTDIR = obj
OPTIONS = -ggdb -g3 -Wall -O0

alpine-server : Shared.a AsyncServerSocket.obj PlayerHandler.obj PacketHandler.obj     Session.obj User.obj Database.obj init
    g++ $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -static \
    -pthread \
    -lmysqlcppconn-static \
            -o $(OUTDIR)/alpine-server src/server/main.cpp \
        $(INTDIR)/AsyncServerSocket.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/PacketHandler.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/Database.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/PlayerHandler.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/Session.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/User.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/Shared.a \
        -lboost_system \
        -lmysqlclient


AsyncServerSocket.obj : src/server/AsyncServerSocket.cpp init
g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/AsyncServerSocket.obj src/server/AsyncServerSocket.cpp

PlayerHandler.obj : src/server/PlayerHandler.cpp init
g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/PlayerHandler.obj src/server/PlayerHandler.cpp

PacketHandler.obj : src/server/PacketHandler.cpp init
g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/PacketHandler.obj src/server/PacketHandler.cpp

Session.obj : src/server/Session.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/Session.obj src/server/Session.cpp

User.obj : src/server/User.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/User.obj src/server/User.cpp

Database.obj : src/server/Database.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/Database.obj src/server/Database.cpp

# Shared.a
Shared.a : Packet.obj Flags.obj AsyncSocket.obj Log.obj init
    ar -cvq $(INTDIR)/Shared.a \
        $(INTDIR)/Packet.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/Flags.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/AsyncSocket.obj \
        $(INTDIR)/Log.obj
    ranlib $(INTDIR)/Shared.a

Packet.obj : src/shared/packet.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/Packet.obj src/shared/packet.cpp

Flags.obj : src/shared/Flags.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/Flags.obj src/shared/Flags.cpp

AsyncSocket.obj : src/shared/AsyncSocket.cpp init
g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/AsyncSocket.obj src/shared/AsyncSocket.cpp

Log.obj : src/shared/Log.cpp init
    g++ -c $(INCLUDES) $(OPTIONS) -o $(INTDIR)/Log.obj src/shared/Log.cpp

init:
    mkdir -p bin obj

clean:
    rm -f $(INTDIR)/*.obj $(INTDIR)/*.a
```

The Code

```
// Excerpt from .hpp file
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
// End excerpt

void Database::connect()
{
    std::stringstream connString;
    connString << "tcp://";
    connString << m_host;
    connString << ":";
    connString << m_port;

    m_driver = get_driver_instance(); // This guy is being a *****
    m_conn = m_driver->connect(connString.str(), m_user, m_password);
    m_conn->setSchema(m_database);
}
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: This issue is nightmare, i am struggling since two days, and not able to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Finally I could successfully compile a program with C++ connector in Ubuntu 10.10.

Initially I faced the same problem with "undefined reference to `get_driver_instance' "  to solve this I declare my driver instance variable of  MySQL_Driver type. For ready reference this type  is defined in mysql_driver.h file. Here is the code snippet I used in my program.

```
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
try {     
    driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
}
```

and I compiled the program with -l mysqlcppconn linker option

Answer (score 5):

Thank you so much, I got it fixed too. I had the exact experience.

I am using Eclipse CDT on 64 Bit CentOS and for anyone reading this here are the following steps .

1. first, be sure that the following are in the code.

`include "mysql_driver.h"`

`include "mysql_connection.h"`

`using namespace sql::mysql;`

2. Be sure that in Eclipse you have specified in your Eclipse project settings.
   the `mysql/include` and `mysql/include/cppconn` directories in your include and then also the `mysql/lib` in the library directory, then and more importantly you specify `-lmysqlcppconn`.
3. Be sure you got the -m64 set in the Eclipse compiler options too.
4. When you run your program, it may complain of missing `libmysqlcppconn.so.1` . Do this, copy `libmysqlcppconn.so.1.0.5` in your `/usr/lib64` directory. Make a link of `libmysqlcppconn.so.1` towards `libmysqlcppconn.so.1.0.5` within that directory.

Your program should now run.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link with

```
-lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlcppconn-static
```

The first library contains the code for the headers in **/usr/include/cppconn/**, and the second library contains the code found in the headers **mysql_driver.h** and **mysql_connection.h**.

Answer (score 2):

The code would be more helpful than the make file but try adding `using namespace sql;` to the top of Database.cpp.

```
// Excerpt from .hpp file
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/connection.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace sql;     // <---- add here
```

Comment: src/server/Database.hpp:13: error: ‘mysql’ is not a namespace-name, Will put up code in a bit

Comment: I said "top" but it needs to go below the includes.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add `-lmysqlcppconn-static` *after* the object files that uses stuff inside that library.

Comment: As in the compilation of that specific .obj or at the bottom of the lib list of the final compile ?

Comment: Tried adding it to both the main compile and the object (-static and -lmysqlcppconn-static)

Answer (score 0):

To me was needed -lmysqlclient

```
g++ -o mariaS2json test.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient
```

And now all works