# Using C++ MySQL Driver on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql, windows

The actual error is a linker error. Undefined reference to get_driver_instance.

Any ideas what the problem is?

This is what I did to install.

- Download and install MinGW to C:\MinGW. http://www.mingw.org/
- Download boost and move the boost folder to C:\MinGW\include
- Download Connector/C++ 1.1.3 http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/
- Move the mysql_connector/include/*.h (recursively) to C:\MinGW\include\
- Move the mysql_connector/lib/mysqlcppconn-static.lib to C:\MinGW\lib\libmysqlcppconn-static.a
- Move the mysql_connector/lib/mysqlconncpp.dll to C:\MinGW\lib\mysqlconncpp.dll
- Alter cppconn/config.h to remove dupication
- Copy the C++ example and name it test.cpp http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html
- add "using namespace sql::mysql" to the file (as recommended)
- run "g++ test.cpp -L C:\MinGW\lib -l mysqlcppconn-static"

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL C++ Connector: undefined reference to \`get\_driver\_instance'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872388/mysql-c-connector-undefined-reference-to-get-driver-instance)

Comment: Why did you tag this with c?

Comment: It is c because c++ is built on c and could potentially be a c directive I am missing. This is not a duplicate because that post (already viewed) did not solve my problem. Nor did many different Google searches. Thank you though.

Comment: why don't you post a runnable sample that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I posted my exact process in the original post...maybe you can tell me what I missed or did wrong based on that.

Comment: What cppconn package are you downloading exactly?  There are probably 50 total.. one of the windows ones?  or building it from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely in a namespace.

throw in this and see what happens:

```
using namespace sql::mysql;
```

edit: Also, did you look through the approximately 869 other times people have asked this same question on stack overflow before posting?

https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+get_driver_instance+site:stackoverflow.com

If that isn't it, it can be a problem with c++ name mangling.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

*Because the name-mangling systems for such features are not standardized across compilers, few linkers can link object code that was produced by different compilers.*

and I think the final answer is here:

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers

another stack overflow answer saying this:

[What problems can appear when using G++ compiled DLL (plugin) in VC++ compiled application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136127/what-problems-can-appear-when-using-g-compiled-dll-plugin-in-vc-compiled-a)

You'll need to build the connector from source using your g++ compiler:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html

Comment: I have tried this already and the first 2 results in the provided Google search I have already looked at.

Comment: So, at this point, I'm thinking it's a c++ compilation issue.  If you look in mysql_driver.cpp, it's not in an extern C section, so my understanding is if you're not using the same C++ compiler as they do, it's not going to find the same library because of how it mangles the names.

Comment: Well this I beleive. I looked around a little bit but I cannot find *.cpp files to compile. All I can find is *.h. Any idea where I can find the *.cpp files (I prefer not to use CMAKE since I have been using MinGW / G++ so far).

Comment: @LoganMurphy in the mysql connector download page drop down, select the one called "source" or something.  I grabbed it and I have a bunch of cpp files.  The file you're looking for is: mysql-connector-c++-1.1.3.tar.gz and there are 110 .cpp files in it.